# error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'DrawString' [DirectXTK]

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am starting with an old project in VC++ using Visual Studio Express 2012. It was after some while of search that I finally got to this.

The Context :

I had an error with the Platform Toolset to start with, like here :

`Error  1   error MSB8020: The builds tools for v143 (Platform Toolset = 'v143') cannot be found. To build using the v143 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install v143 to build using the v143 build tools.`

but got solved referring here : [Visual Studio wants to build with wrong platform toolset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292810/visual-studio-wants-to-build-with-wrong-platform-toolset)

I have set the platform toolset in project properties->General->Platform Toolset to -> Visual Studio 2012.

The Problem :

Now, this is the error that I am getting :

`error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'DrawString'`

Here is the code part :

```
void XM_CALLCONV DrawString(_In_ ISpriteFontRenderer* spriteBatch, _In_z_ wchar_t const* text, FXMVECTOR position, FXMVECTOR color) const; // error here
```

Others errors follow, but of I could get a direction, how to downgrade the codebase to a 2010 version of VC++ here, I could manage the rest.

I have a full 175 errors appearing.

I am new to VC++ and DirectXDK, though I am from a game development background. Just getting used to the new environment.

Any directions appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of the `XM_CALLCONV` macro.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, I am here looking here for a way to integrate the correct SDK of sorts with the IDE here. Currently, I am clueless as to the definitions and signatures.

Comment: So,  I change the platform toolset to _V110_, in the project settings, it gets me to the right development environment. I am now looking for a documentation that I could refer to to downgrade the project from the original _v141_ it was built with to _v110_. I guess that defines the problem now.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, do we have a reference of some sort as to how to refer to method signatures for each version ?